# Parsing(?) Facebook username right after logging in

Tags: php, facebook, parse-platform

Hi Facebook Developers!

We have an ongoing thesis about a personalized web security, specifically about websites that have logins (Facebook and GMail). I'm not sure whether it needs a web extension because we're developing a windows application that tracks a SPECIFIC USERNAME on a website (not including the password).

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can´t get the username anymore

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But would there be any alternative if I want to track the owner's account from his or her own laptop or desktop? Thanks!

Comment: yes, the app scoped user id

Comment: Can I implement this directly on our windows application or does it need to be on the web extension still?

Comment: you need to start trying stuff, don´t just ask for every single step ;) > https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: Yup on it thank you so much! :D